# Creating a CALENDAR TABLE in Dataverse for using in POWER APPS

Tags: calendar, powerapps, dataverse

I am trying to make a Calendar Table in Dataverse to connect it to several tables I am using in PowerApps. I would like to know if there is a possibility to create a Calendar Table (like in PowerBI) or which would be the best option in this case. Should I export the one I have from PowerBI to Dataverse? It did not seem to be the best option for me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the table and a column of type date, you should get items into that in a way.

Dataverse does not have the PowerBI Autocalendar function or whatever, so either create a flow to fill items, make a powerapp to fill, create a row in excel and import it. It’s the same as a SQL Server, it needs to be filled in.